# How to reprogram mouse button

Tags: microsoft-mouse

Running 20.04.2 LTS, using a Microsoft Comfort Optical Mouse 3000. The thumb button (left edge of mouse) functions as "forward" and I want to change it to "back". Any tips?

Comment: Have you tried `xev` to identify the button and then remapping it?

Comment: Pedro: Not until you just mentioned it. I'm new to this. I used xev -event mouse and found that it's button 9. Now what?

Answer (score 0):

First, identify your mouse's `id` through the command `xinput`. In this example, what we are looking for is the `id=9`:

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE                  id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Now, let's discover all the buttons available on your mouse and their order, using the command `xinput --list <id>`, substituting `<id>` for your mouse's id found earlier:

```
$ xinput --list 9
PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE                    id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    Reporting 7 classes:
        Class originated from: 9. Type: XIButtonClass
        Buttons supported: 7
        Button labels: "Button Left" "Button Middle" "Button Right" "Button Wheel Up" "Button Wheel Down" "Button Horiz Wheel Left" "Button Horiz Wheel Right"
```

Now we know how many buttons are supported, and their order, given by "Button labels". In the example, "Button Left" is `1`, "Button Middle" is `2`, and so  on.

I don't know the exact order of the buttons of your mouse, as you should discover it as described above. But suppose your `"Back button"`'s number is 6 and `"Forward button"`'s number is 7, and there are 11 buttons supported. Run this command, substituting `<id>` for your mouse's id:

```
xinput set-button-map <id> 1 2 3 4 5 7 6 8 9 10 11
```

Comment: Here's the output I got after running xinput as suggested. No button labels!

Microsoft Microsoft Optical Mouse with Tilt Wheel Consumer Control id=16 [slave  keyboard (3)]
 Reporting 1 classes:
  Class originated from: 16. Type: XIKeyClass
  Keycodes supported: 248

Comment: @Ancient it seems the mouse also creates a slave keyboard, however you found out before with `xev` that it also returned a ButtonPress event, and not a KeyPress event, so, there must be a slave pointer linked to this mouse. Please run `xinput list --long | awk '/master keyboard/{exit}1'` and edit your question with the output. This will allow us to check all your pointers.

Comment: I tried to paste the entire output, but this system is saying it's too long by 5686 characters. Is there another way to share it here?

Comment: @Ancient You may use [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com) or [Paste Ubuntu](http://paste.ubuntu.com).

Comment: Thanks. I'm away from the computer for a day or two. To be continued!